# ngcordova camera image overlay

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am building an app on Ionic and have integrated the ngcordova API. I'm wondering if there is a way to select an image from a gallery in my app and then open the camera and overlay, position, resize, screenshot etc the image on top of the camera view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do that.

You can wrap a `<video>` item and a `<canvas>` item in a `<div>` container, then attach camera to video (use [getUserMedia() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)).

You can capture screenshots from your camera: try using [drawImage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) of canvas/context (see for example http://appcropolis.com/blog/web-technology/using-html5-canvas-to-capture-frames-from-a-video/).

The `<div>` container can be used to keep (via CSS) video and canvas elements together and manage resize/position properly.

The `<canvas>` element can be used to draw pictures overlayed to the video (using a CSS opacity value).

GetUserMedia API (and other WebRTC APIs)  are available on Android thanks to [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) which is an alternative WebView in an Ionic/Cordova project.

Comment: I was under the impression that getusermedia doesn't work for mobile? Is this solution a truly viable strategy to accomplish the image overlay on a live camera stream with ionic for both droid and ios?

Comment: I have to add that on Android it is possible thanks to [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) which is an alternative WebView in an Ionic/Cordova project. There is also a Crosswalk project for iOS (see https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios.html) but I haven't used it yet.